# Question got a random tag added to it in review

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, tags, review-queues

I was surprised to see [this review item](https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/23388690) appear in my queue since I don't have Python as one of my filter tags. I switched to the "Question (revised)" tab and noticed it was tagged [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) which is in my filter, so I went to [the question itself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56681552/how-to-extract-parts-of-a-string-in-python) to edit the tag out and saw that not only does it not have that tag, but it *never did*. So where did the tag come from?

Comment: Fake tags are often included in review audits. See [Are review audits supposed to be only for the tags that you filtered](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/345988/4642212).

Comment: the question has been improved since closing

Comment: Gotta love the dead giveaway of a `[php][c++]` sight...

Comment: @Siguza [1,146 questions there...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php%20c%2b%2b) Maybe throw in assembly or fortran? :)

Comment: @ASh That's why I didn't realize it was an audit. I skipped it in fact since I'm not enough of a Python expert to judge if it's still unclear or not.

Comment: you passed the audit...

Comment: @TrebledJ: and I just upvoted one because it was a legit question using both languages and knowing both is required to understand it.

Answer (score 4):

Well, when I was doing focus-filtered reviews, I could instantly identify audits because they didn't match the filters.

So now it adds tags to match the filters. Expect quite a few audit fails with closed->unclear due to wildly mismatching tags. I haven't decided if these are legit audit fails or bad audit fails or not. Edit->correct tags is the correct action which counts as neither. If I had my druthers I'd have it immediately go to pass on clicking edit if the audit generator retagged a question.

Comment: The audit system has always added the tag you're filtering on if you're filtering. It makes sense because if you're filtering on a low traffic tag, there may be no posts that qualify as being audits matching that filter.

Comment: @TinyGiant No, the audit system has not always added the tag you're filtering on. The last time I noticed it, the audit system *sometimes* added the appropriate tag and sometimes it did not. I've seen it do both in the same session of me reviewing in a queue, but on different questions.

Comment: @Makyen By that I meant that it isn't a new thing, it has been around since the inception of the audit system or shortly thereafter. This answer makes it seem like a dev recently spent time implementing this, which is not the case.

Comment: @TinyGiant: I was using more complex filters that included a tag filter as a component. Possible it doesn't do it for more complex filters.